# Oxwell does not load graphics on webpage

Tags: server, apache2, php, lamp

Im running Ubuntu server 10.4.4 with lamp installed. I have setup Oxwell by creating a folder in /var/www/oxwell and unzipping contents. I have also chmod -R 777 /oxwell for testing. Opening a webrowser it is only showing text and no graphics. I have managed to install Oxwell from the browser but it still is showing text only. Please see example below.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was blanks in the http section under ow_includes/config.php

Comment: Could you explain what you did to fix it?

Comment: I went into the http section under ow_includes/config.php and removed the blanks from the address.